# create SamlAssertion and token after receiveing Saml-token from sts

Tags: saml

I'm rather new to consuming webservices so I hope my question makes sense
I need to consume a webservice using the WS-Security SAML Token Profile / Holder-of-Key principle. I succeeded to get a "samlAssertion" xml from an STS:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns="" xmlns:ns10="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" AssertionID="ID_ab1a7c5f-a0cb-4e6f-9342-d623b2095d3b" IssueInstant="2015-08-11T10:44:39.989Z" ...>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-08-11T10:44:39.927Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-08-11T11:44:39.927Z" />
    <saml:AuthenticationStatement ...>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameIdentifier ...>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:holder-of-key</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                            ...
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
    </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameidformat:X509SubjectName">...</saml:NameIdentifier>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:holder-of-key</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                            ...
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Attribute ...>
                ...
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
    <dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:SignedInfo>
            <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <dsig:Reference URI="#ID_ab1a7c5f-a0cb-4e6f-9342-d623b2095d3b">
                <dsig:Transforms>
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <dsig:DigestValue>...</dsig:DigestValue>
            </dsig:Reference>
        </dsig:SignedInfo>
        <dsig:SignatureValue>...</dsig:SignatureValue>
    </dsig:Signature>
</saml:Assertion>
```

I think I need to use WIF now to continue so I want to create a SamlAssertion-object out of the received xml.

this is my code:

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(recievedXml));
 assertion.ReadXml(XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(reader),
                new SamlSerializer(),
                new WSSecurityTokenSerializer(),
                null);
```

However this code is resulting into the following error:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ski

- What does this mean?
- Is there another way to create the SamlAssertion?
- Do I actually need the Samlassertion to continue?